# DVD player Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, dvd, media-player, vlc-media-player

Hello everyone at SeverFault. I am new to this fourm. I have been using ubuntu since 8.04. Here is my problem. When I try to watch one of my cisco videos I get wmas error. I never had to use this format before. I went on ubuntu fourm they told me to use vlc media. I am using vlc media. mplayer, it still have error with that, sounds and video. Is there a program that I could use to watch wmas files on my ubuntu 9.10.

It is a laptop 
ACer Extensa 5620z.

Thank you for who ever will help !!

Comment: I closed this migrated duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/122877/good-dvd-media-player-for-ubuntu-9-10

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs). to open WMA files, try [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) to play and record most common multimedia formats, including MP3, DVD, Flash, Quicktime, WMA and WMV, including both standalone files and content embedded in web pages.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```