# Good DvD media player for Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, dvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DVD player Ubuntu 9.10](https://superuser.com/questions/122757/dvd-player-ubuntu-9-10)

Hello everyone, in serverfault. I just have a question? I have a load of cisco videos, that I enjoy watching. The format is wma. Is there any good wma formats out there. I have been reviewing a few, I just would like to hear it for you guys. Sorry I am using ubuntu 9.10

Comment: Duplicate Question : http://superuser.com/questions/122757/dvd-player-ubuntu-9-10

Answer (score 0):

For all videos I am using VLC and sometimes mplayer/smplayer. Other people use Xine or players based on GStreamer.

Comment: I tried vlc media and it does it like my wma files. I haven't tried xine, i  will let you know if that works?